# Extension of closed operator densely defined

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, topological-vector-spaces, dense-subspaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space. Suppose $A:D(A)\subset X \longrightarrow X$ is a closed linear operator and $D(A)$ is dense in $X$. Prove that $A$ cannot be extended as a closed linear operator to any subspace $\mathcal{D} \supset D(A)$. The density of $D(A)$ is needed, since the restriction of a closed linear operator to a closed subspace is still a closed linear operator. Any hint is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Before answering I should have told you that on this forum it is more or less expected to at least show what you've tried or research you've done. For example, here, what did you attempt to show, and where did you fail? That type of info is valuable since it lets us help you in a possibly more adequate way, but it can also be valuable to you to pinpoint exactly where the problem lies so you can better explain what you don't understand or can't achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A counterexample to your claim on Hilbert spaces would be the closure $\bar{A}$ of any non-self-adjoint but symmetric, densely defined and not bounded operator $A$ admitting a self-adjoint extension (which exists because you can construct symmetric operators with any two deficiency indices if I recall correctly, so in particular you can take $A$ with deficiency indices $(1,1)$). The not bounded part is optional, it's just so that we know the self-adjoint extension can't be bounded either, and thus the domain cannot be the whole space, in order to have a non-trivial example. Said self-adjoint extension is closed and thus must extend the aforementioned closure $\bar{A}$ at least, which exists because all symmetric operators are closable.

For a clear-cut example, the following operator from Example 1 in Chapters X of Reed and Simon's *Fourier Analysis, Self-Adjointness* (volume 2 of their series of books) has deficiency indices $(1,1)$:
$$T : f \in H^1_0(0,1) \subset L^2(0,1) \mapsto i f' \in L^2(0,1)$$
whose adjoint is still $f \mapsto if'$ but with domain $H^1(0,1)$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you elaborate on the counter-example? Does there exist a closed symmetric operator defined on a dense subset that has a closed (proper) extension? It was not clear to me that your example is closed and densely defined to begin with. Thanks.

Comment: @M.Rubick would this be better? For the construction of such an $A$, I think it's either in the Reed&Simon volume 1 or in Davies's *Spectral Theory and Differential Operators*, I don't have them on me right now though.

Comment: Thanks again. Amazing answer. Would you help me understand some details? How can we guarantee that such $\bar A$ exists? Its a closed, densely defined, non-self adjoint and symmetric operator on Hilbert space admitting an unbounded symmetric closed extension. Are there examples of that? I don't undertand the statement you made about deficiencies. Thank you very much!

Comment: @M.Rubick It would take a little while to explain properly, but essentially the deficiency indices of a symmetric operator are the quantities $\dim \ker(A^* \pm i\mathrm{Id})$, which represent the deficiency of $A^*$ in terms of how close it is from being symmetric. An important criterion regarding these indices is that they're equal (as cardinal numbers) iff $A$ admits self-adjoint extensions, and both equal to $0$ iff $A$ is essentially self-adjoint. The usual way to show this is through Cayley transforms, as symmetric resp. self-adjoint extensions of a symmetric operator are... (1/2)

Comment: ... in a one-to-one correspondence with isometric resp. unitary extensions of its Cayley transform. Anyway, it just so happens that you can construct operators with any two given deficiency indices (Problem 1 of ReedSimon volume 2, I was able to check today), and since Hilbert spaces with the same dimension (as in the cardinal of any of its orthonormal bases) are isomorphic (in particular separable Hilbert spaces are isomorphic to each other), once you have one example you can transpose it into your space of choice. (2/2)

Comment: Great answer. Thank you very much. It was a pleasure to learn about these things.